# How to resolve nested arraylist output in java

Tags: java

As per some condition i add some values(it may single or multiple values) in my Arraylist.

in common method:

```
List<Object> listsALL.....

listsALL.add(sItems2);
```

value will return to calling method.

i can access values below way

```
sItems100.add(String.valueOf(listsALL.get(3)));
```

output like

```
sItems100---------------- [[Item 5, Item 7]]
```

While fetching the value from sItems100 and add into nested list, i'm getting below output

```
[[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6], [[Item 5, Item 7]]]
```

but i expect like

```
[[Item 1, Item 2, Item 6], [Item 5, Item 7]]
```

How to resolve this, any one can help in this?

Comment: Use `List<List<YourExactObject>>` instead of `List<Object>`.

Comment: I tried to return Integer, String - values with in the same list, so i tried with List<Object>. can i use List<List<YourExactObject>> for My need?. if yes please let me know- Thanks

Comment: Store your desired `int`s and `String`s and any other desired data in a custom class. Then, for each group of this data, store it in an instance of `YourCustomClass`, group them in `List<YourCustomClass>` as desired and make a `List<List<YourCustomClass>>` to store all the data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
List<Object> listsALL = new ArrayList<Object>();

List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(6);

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(5);
list2.add(7);

listAll.add(list1);
listAll.add(list2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i'm not looking this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a great idea to keep a List of generic Objects of different types (e.g. List in your case), and to insert both an singular Object and a List in this initial list.

If it is possible, try using a

```
List<List<Object>>
```

instead. Don't forget that List is an interface, implemented below by ArrayList class.

```
     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();         

     ArrayList<String> firstElement = new ArrayList<String>();
     firstElement.add("Object1");

     ArrayList<String> secondElement = new ArrayList<String>();
     secondElement.add("Object2");
     secondElement.add("Object3");         

     aList.add(firstElement);
     aList.add(secondElement);

     System.out.println(aList.get(0).get(0));
     System.out.println(aList.get(1).get(0));
     System.out.println(aList.get(1).get(1));
```

Here you have two similar Lists in the initial aList, one with only one element, one with two elements.

If you want to use both an Object and a List inside your initial list, you might want to check how to use instanceof operator and casting in Java.

```
if(aList.get(1) instanceof ArrayList){
         System.out.println("True");
     }
     else {
         System.out.println("False");
     }
```

Here is the full example of using instanceof:

```
 ArrayList<Object> aList = new ArrayList<Object>();         

 String firstElement = "Object1";

 ArrayList<String> secondElement = new ArrayList<String>();
 secondElement.add("Object2");
 secondElement.add("Object3");         

 aList.add(firstElement);
 aList.add(secondElement);

 for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++){
     if (aList.get(i) instanceof String ){
         System.out.println( (String) aList.get(i) );
     } 
     if (aList.get(i) instanceof ArrayList){
         System.out.println( ((ArrayList<String>)aList.get(i)).get(0) );
     }         
 }
```

So the initial aList holds two types of Objects in this case, String and ArrayList. When iterating the list, you use instanceof operator to see what type of Object it is, and cast it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,actually i tried with this way initially for my needs, but i can't return all the type of values with single return type.so tried with List<Object>. Do you have any tips for return type of values with single return? please let me know.... Thanks

Comment: I've edited the initial response to show the example of instanceof usage. Is this what you are looking for ? If not, I am missing the question, what do you mean by return type of values with single return ?

Comment: I mean values of diff types like integer, String,... with single return to calling method.